# Make my design ready for printing

Tags: adobe-illustrator, print-design

I know there is a lot of information about it but I couldn't find myself.
I have some design in which I want to translate to real life measurement, in millimeters,

1. How would I set my artboard size to be A4 ? I know how to change its size, but there is no option to set it to be A4 exactly.

2.When I play with my design inside the artboard, how would I know whats the size in real life ?  in mm ?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi I just answered you below although don't forget to set your measurements to mm. Press shift+R for the rulers to show up and then right click on one of them and choose the units you wish to work with.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To set up your document to A4 you can do it when you create a new document/artboard like this:

[image: 1]]

Just choose A4 on the Size drop-down menu.

To change the artboard size on an already set up document you will have to select the artboard edition tool. You can do this by using the keyboard shortcut shift+O then press enter on your keyboard and this window will show up

[image: 1]]

Then choose Preset A4,if that is the size you wish. Also you  can choose the orientation by selecting either the portrait icon or the landscape one.

For your second question you can know the size of one element by selecting it and  look for the size boxes on your Illustrator top bar as shown:

[image: 3]]

If you are using a smaller screen than mine you should have something like this:

[image: 4]]

In this case you will have to click on the "Transform" orange text on the top bar and the measurements should show up in a small window.

[image: 5]]

If you select all the objects inside the document it will give you the overall measurements of the objects all together.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Don't forget: you might need to set your preferences to display units in millimeters first.

Comment: hahaha precisely! I just commented above that I forgot to cover that "detail". Thanks for the heads up :)